# Rails App Heroku PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have been searching for 12 hours to a solution to this problem, please can someone help with the following.

Locally my app is working as it should no errors, as soon as I deploy to heroku it just refuses to display the login/sign up pages.

I have tried all my technical ability is capable off. 12 hours of research and i cant find anything.

Puma caught this error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "servers" does not exist
LINE 9:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"servers"'::regclass

Couldn't create 'defml5i7le0i08' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.
^

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/netguru-training/wroclaw-ror-workshops-2015-december/issues/4

The issue was devise only creates a migration and does not create the table.

The solution was to delete migrations, generate the User model first to create the table then run devise MODEL for the routes.